# Python I/O both read and append (write)

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-io, io

I'm learning python and I saw this 'a+' mode for handling file streams. Why can't I do something like the code below to first **read** and check the file if it contains anything, and then **write** to it based on the evaluation?

```
with open('output.txt', 'a+') as logfile:
    textOfFile = logfile.read()
    if textOfFile != '':
        logfile.write("\r\nFile contains text")
    else:
        logfile.write("\r\nFile is empty")
```

The code above gave me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/scripts/testfile.py", line 22, in <module>
    logfile.write("anything man")
IOError: [Errno 0] Error
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this not possible to do? What is then the point of 'a+'?

Comment: the traceback doesn't correspond to the code

Answer (score 1):

The a+ file mode appends to the file without overwriting it's current contents. In order to solve your problem, you'll need to first read the file's in reading mode which is the default like so:

```
text_r = open('text.txt').read()
text_a = open('text.txt', 'a+')

if text_r != '':
    text_a.write('\r\nFile contains text')
    text_a.close()

else:
    text_a.write('\r\nFile is empty')
    text_a.close()
```